# AngularJS select tag not dropping down

Tags: css, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu, ng-options

[image]

I am writing an dropdown select menu using AngularJS's ng-options. Selecting and submitting works fine. But as seen in the picture, it is not dropping down like it is supposed to; it shows everything instead. This is the code for select:

```
<label>Role Type: 
    <select ng-options="role for role in roles" ng-model="Role_Type" size = "10">
        <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.roles = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-options can be confusing to get used to, so I don't blame you getting on the wrong track. However, the problem is actually just that you're displaying 10 items from the select at once.

Just remove this and your problem should be gone:
`size = "10"`

check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size

Comment: Perfect @wesww thank you. I thought size controls the size of the input box

Comment: glad I could help : )